# Adding a scrollbar to a frame using Tkinter (Python)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I've a simple GUI thats shows the users some options, after putting the number of the initial options to be shown. In this case, 4:

[image: initial]

By clicking on `Add row` you can add a row to the GUI. The thing is that if the user wants 100 options, the GUI becomes extra big and all the options are not shown.
[image: big]

So I would like to have a scrollbar only on the options space, not the rest parts. Sorry for the bad Photoshop, but I would like to have something like this:
[image: desiredsolution]

The options space is the `FrameTwo`, so I would like to have the entire `FrameTwo` inside of scrollbar like the image above.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from Tkinter import *
import Image
import ImageTk
import tkFileDialog
import datetime

class Planificador(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.master.title("Plan")
        self.frameOne = Frame(self.master)
        self.frameOne.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.frameTwo = Frame(self.master)
        self.frameTwo.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.frameThree = Frame(self.master)
        self.frameThree.grid(row=2, column=0)

        # Borrar esto?
        self.txt = Text(self)
        self.txt.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.piezastext = Label(self.frameOne, text = " Amount of pieces ", justify="center")
        self.piezastext.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.entrypiezas = Entry(self.frameOne,width=3)
        self.entrypiezas.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=(5,5))
        self.aceptarnumpiezas = Button(self.frameOne,text="Click me", command=self.aceptar_piezas,width=8)
        self.aceptarnumpiezas.grid(row=6, column=0, pady=(5,5))

    def aceptar_piezas(self):
        try:
            val = int(self.entrypiezas.get())
            self.aceptar_piezas_ok()
        except ValueError:
            showerror('Error', "Introduce un numero")

    def aceptar_piezas_ok(self):
        self.num_piezas = self.entrypiezas.get()

        self.piezastext.grid_remove()
        self.entrypiezas.grid_remove()
        self.aceptarnumpiezas.grid_remove()

        self.optionmenus_piezas = list()
        self.numpiezas = []
        self.numerolotes = []
        self.optionmenus_prioridad = list()
        self.lotes = list()

        self.mispiezas = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']

        self.n = 1
        while self.n <= int(self.num_piezas):
            self.textopieza = Label(self.frameTwo, text = "Pieza: ", justify="left")
            self.textopieza.grid(row=self.n, column=0)

            var = StringVar()
            menu = OptionMenu(self.frameTwo, var, *self.mispiezas)
            menu.config(width=10)
            menu.grid(row=self.n, column=1)
            var.set("One")
            self.optionmenus_piezas.append((menu, var))

            self.numpiezastext = Label(self.frameTwo, text = "Numero de piezas: ", justify="center")
            self.numpiezastext.grid(row=self.n, column=2, padx=(10,0))
            self.entrynumpiezas = Entry(self.frameTwo,width=6)
            self.entrynumpiezas.grid(row=self.n, column=3, padx=(0,10))
            self.entrynumpiezas.insert(0, "0")

            self.textoprioridad = Label(self.frameTwo, text = "Prioridad: ", justify="center")
            self.textoprioridad.grid(row=self.n, column=4)
            var2 = StringVar()
            menu2 = OptionMenu(self.frameTwo, var2, "Normal", "Baja", "Primera pieza", "Esta semana")
            menu2.config(width=10)
            menu2.grid(row=self.n, column=5)
            var2.set("Normal")
            self.optionmenus_prioridad.append((menu2, var2))

            self.lotestext = Label(self.frameTwo, text = "Por lotes?", justify="center")
            self.lotestext.grid(row=self.n, column=6, padx=(10,0))
            self.var1 = IntVar()
            self.entrynumlotes = Checkbutton(self.frameTwo, variable=self.var1)
            self.entrynumlotes.grid(row=self.n, column=7, padx=(5,10))
            self.lotes.append(self.var1)
            self.numpiezas.append(self.entrynumpiezas)

            self.n += 1

        self.anadirpiezas = Button(self.frameThree, text="Add row", command=self.addpieza, width=10)
        self.anadirpiezas.grid(row=0, column=2, pady=(10,10))

        self.calculotext = Label(self.frameThree, text = "Other stuff ")
        self.calculotext.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=(10,0), pady=(10,10))

        self.graspbutton = Button(self.frameThree, text="OPT 1", width=10)
        self.graspbutton.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.parettobutton = Button(self.frameThree, text="OPT 2",width=10)
        self.parettobutton.grid(row=2, column=2, pady=(10,10), padx=(10,0))

        self.parettoEvolbutton = Button(self.frameThree, text="OPT 2", width=10)
        self.parettoEvolbutton.grid(row=2, column=3, pady=(10,10), padx=(10,0))


    def addpieza(self):
            self.textopiezanuevo = Label(self.frameTwo, text = "Pieza: ", justify="left")
            self.textopiezanuevo.grid(row=int(self.num_piezas)+1, column=0)

            var = StringVar()
            menu = OptionMenu(self.frameTwo, var, *self.mispiezas)
            menu.grid(row=self.n, column=1)
            menu.config(width=10)
            menu.grid(row=int(self.num_piezas)+1, column=1)
            var.set("One")
            self.optionmenus_piezas.append((menu, var))

            self.numpiezastext = Label(self.frameTwo, text = "Numero de piezas: ", justify="center")
            self.numpiezastext.grid(row=int(self.num_piezas)+1, column=2, padx=(10,0))
            self.entrynumpiezas = Entry(self.frameTwo,width=6)
            self.entrynumpiezas.grid(row=int(self.num_piezas)+1, column=3, padx=(0,10))
            self.entrynumpiezas.insert(0, "0")

            self.textoprioridad = Label(self.frameTwo, text = "Prioridad: ", justify="center")
            self.textoprioridad.grid(row=int(self.num_piezas)+1, column=4)
            var2 = StringVar()
            menu2 = OptionMenu(self.frameTwo, var2, "Normal", "Baja", "Primera pieza", "Esta semana")
            menu2.config(width=10)
            menu2.grid(row=int(self.num_piezas)+1, column=5)
            var2.set("Normal")
            self.optionmenus_prioridad.append((menu2, var2))

            self.lotestext = Label(self.frameTwo, text = "Por lotes?", justify="center")
            self.lotestext.grid(row=int(self.num_piezas)+1, column=6, padx=(10,0))
            self.var1 = IntVar()
            self.entrynumlotes = Checkbutton(self.frameTwo, variable=self.var1)
            self.entrynumlotes.grid(row=int(self.num_piezas)+1, column=7, padx=(5,10))
            self.lotes.append(self.var1)

            self.numpiezas.append(self.entrynumpiezas)
            self.num_piezas = int(self.num_piezas)+1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    aplicacion = Planificador(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

`FrameOne` is used to put an image I removed to make this example more simple. And `FrameThree` are the buttons you can see at the bottom of the GUI.

So it would be very helpful if someone could give me a hand and tell me how to put the entire `FrameTwo` inside of a scrollbar as you can see on the third image.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I see there are no anwers, I would like to know if it's possible to build a fixed size interface, of for example 500x400 and put a scrollbar for the entire thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

One of your problems, is that "frameTwo" has no limits to it's size. If you don't limit it's size, any scrollbar you add, never will act. But limiting the size of you frame have the inconvenient of limit the number of lines you can grid, making the scrollbar useless again.

A solution is creating a frame inside the "frameTwo", to receive the pieces you create. This way, by one hand, allow you to limit the size of "frameTwo" and attach the scrollbar to it, and by other hand, allow you to grid the pieces you add to the frame located inside "frameTwo", named, let's say, "ListFrame". when "ListFrame" size becomes bigger than "frameTwo" size, you can now make the scrollbar work.

I change your code with the changes mentioned above. Check it out.
The changes are commented in the code. 
Sorry for the short explanation, but i'm a bit hurry. I may edit this answer when I have more time.

PS: Sorry if my english is not the best

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from Tkinter import *
import Image
import ImageTk
import tkFileDialog
import datetime

class Planificador(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.master.title("Plan")
        self.frameOne = Frame(self.master)
        self.frameOne.grid(row=0,column=0)

        self.frameTwo = Frame(self.master)
        self.frameTwo.grid(row=1, column=0)

        #Creating of a new frame, inside of "frameTwo" to the objects to be inserted
        #Creating a scrollbar

        #The reason for this, is to attach the scrollbar to "FrameTwo", and when the size of frame "ListFrame" exceed the size of frameTwo, the scrollbar acts
        self.canvas=Canvas(self.frameTwo)
        self.listFrame=Frame(self.canvas)
        self.scrollb=Scrollbar(self.master, orient="vertical",command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.scrollb.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nsew')  #grid scrollbar in master, but
        self.canvas['yscrollcommand'] = self.scrollb.set   #attach scrollbar to frameTwo

        self.canvas.create_window((0,0),window=self.listFrame,anchor='nw')
        self.listFrame.bind("<Configure>", self.AuxscrollFunction)
        self.scrollb.grid_forget()                         #Forget scrollbar because the number of pieces remains undefined by the user. But this not destroy it. It will be "remembered" later.

        self.canvas.pack(side="left")
        self.frameThree = Frame(self.master)
        self.frameThree.grid(row=2, column=0)

        # Borrar esto?
        self.txt = Text(self)
        self.txt.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.piezastext = Label(self.frameOne, text = " Amount of pieces ", justify="center")
        self.piezastext.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.entrypiezas = Entry(self.frameOne,width=3)
        self.entrypiezas.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=(5,5))
        self.aceptarnumpiezas = Button(self.frameOne,text="Click me", command=self.aceptar_piezas,width=8)
        self.aceptarnumpiezas.grid(row=6, column=0, pady=(5,5))

    def AuxscrollFunction(self,event):
        #You need to set a max size for frameTwo. Otherwise, it will grow as needed, and scrollbar do not act
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"),width=600,height=500)

    def aceptar_piezas(self):



        #IMPORTANT!!! All the objects are now created in "ListFrame" and not in "frameTwo"
        #I perform the alterations. Check it out
        try:
            val = int(self.entrypiezas.get())
            self.aceptar_piezas_ok()
            self.scrollb.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nsew')  #grid scrollbar in master, because user had defined the numer of pieces
        except ValueError:
            showerror('Error', "Introduce un numero")

    def aceptar_piezas_ok(self):
        self.num_piezas = self.entrypiezas.get()

        self.piezastext.grid_remove()
        self.entrypiezas.grid_remove()
        self.aceptarnumpiezas.grid_remove()

        self.optionmenus_piezas = list()
        self.numpiezas = []
        self.numerolotes = []
        self.optionmenus_prioridad = list()
        self.lotes = list()

        self.mispiezas = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']

        self.n = 1
        while self.n <= int(self.num_piezas):
            self.textopieza = Label(self.listFrame, text = "Pieza: ", justify="left")
            self.textopieza.grid(row=self.n, column=0)

            var = StringVar()
            menu = OptionMenu(self.listFrame, var, *self.mispiezas)
            menu.config(width=10)
            menu.grid(row=self.n, column=1)
            var.set("One")
            self.optionmenus_piezas.append((menu, var))

            self.numpiezastext = Label(self.listFrame, text = "Numero de piezas: ", justify="center")
            self.numpiezastext.grid(row=self.n, column=2, padx=(10,0))
            self.entrynumpiezas = Entry(self.listFrame,width=6)
            self.entrynumpiezas.grid(row=self.n, column=3, padx=(0,10))
            self.entrynumpiezas.insert(0, "0")

            self.textoprioridad = Label(self.listFrame, text = "Prioridad: ", justify="center")
            self.textoprioridad.grid(row=self.n, column=4)
            var2 = StringVar()
            menu2 = OptionMenu(self.listFrame, var2, "Normal", "Baja", "Primera pieza", "Esta semana")
            menu2.config(width=10)
            menu2.grid(row=self.n, column=5)
            var2.set("Normal")
            self.optionmenus_prioridad.append((menu2, var2))

            self.lotestext = Label(self.listFrame, text = "Por lotes?", justify="center")
            self.lotestext.grid(row=self.n, column=6, padx=(10,0))
            self.var1 = IntVar()
            self.entrynumlotes = Checkbutton(self.listFrame, variable=self.var1)
            self.entrynumlotes.grid(row=self.n, column=7, padx=(5,10))
            self.lotes.append(self.var1)
            self.numpiezas.append(self.entrynumpiezas)

            self.n += 1

        self.anadirpiezas = Button(self.frameThree, text="Add row", command=self.addpieza, width=10)
        self.anadirpiezas.grid(row=0, column=2, pady=(10,10))

        self.calculotext = Label(self.frameThree, text = "Other stuff ")
        self.calculotext.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=(10,0), pady=(10,10))

        self.graspbutton = Button(self.frameThree, text="OPT 1", width=10)
        self.graspbutton.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.parettobutton = Button(self.frameThree, text="OPT 2",width=10)
        self.parettobutton.grid(row=2, column=2, pady=(10,10), padx=(10,0))

        self.parettoEvolbutton = Button(self.frameThree, text="OPT 2", width=10)
        self.parettoEvolbutton.grid(row=2, column=3, pady=(10,10), padx=(10,0))


    def addpieza(self):
            self.textopiezanuevo = Label(self.listFrame, text = "Pieza: ", justify="left")
            self.textopiezanuevo.grid(row=int(self.num_piezas)+1, column=0)

            var = StringVar()
            menu = OptionMenu(self.listFrame, var, *self.mispiezas)
            menu.grid(row=self.n, column=1)
            menu.config(width=10)
            menu.grid(row=int(self.num_piezas)+1, column=1)
            var.set("One")
            self.optionmenus_piezas.append((menu, var))

            self.numpiezastext = Label(self.listFrame, text = "Numero de piezas: ", justify="center")
            self.numpiezastext.grid(row=int(self.num_piezas)+1, column=2, padx=(10,0))
            self.entrynumpiezas = Entry(self.listFrame,width=6)
            self.entrynumpiezas.grid(row=int(self.num_piezas)+1, column=3, padx=(0,10))
            self.entrynumpiezas.insert(0, "0")

            self.textoprioridad = Label(self.listFrame, text = "Prioridad: ", justify="center")
            self.textoprioridad.grid(row=int(self.num_piezas)+1, column=4)
            var2 = StringVar()
            menu2 = OptionMenu(self.listFrame, var2, "Normal", "Baja", "Primera pieza", "Esta semana")
            menu2.config(width=10)
            menu2.grid(row=int(self.num_piezas)+1, column=5)
            var2.set("Normal")
            self.optionmenus_prioridad.append((menu2, var2))

            self.lotestext = Label(self.listFrame, text = "Por lotes?", justify="center")
            self.lotestext.grid(row=int(self.num_piezas)+1, column=6, padx=(10,0))
            self.var1 = IntVar()
            self.entrynumlotes = Checkbutton(self.listFrame, variable=self.var1)
            self.entrynumlotes.grid(row=int(self.num_piezas)+1, column=7, padx=(5,10))
            self.lotes.append(self.var1)

            self.numpiezas.append(self.entrynumpiezas)
            self.num_piezas = int(self.num_piezas)+1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    aplicacion = Planificador(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -4):

You have option menus, labels, entry boxes, and checkbuttons in FrameTwo.  How would you expect a scrollbar for the entire frame would work?  Would it scroll all widgets at the same time?  Tkinter scrollbars are generally attached to listboxes, canvases, entry widgets, and text fields.  http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-scrollbar-patterns.htm  Come up with a simple example that illustrates the problem for further help.

Comment: This is not an answer, it's a comment and a request for verification.