# scrollbar for labels frame in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a scroll bar for a window created in my gui using tk.Toplevel. The frame currently often fills up with long grids of strings that are added one buy one. The rest of the GUI allows a user to write to a series of fields which are displayed one after another using a grid.

The data might look something like this:

> sadas sfafaf fsaafads fdsafsf dfsfdsf fssfs fsfsfsfs fsfsfs sfsfsfs
>   fsssfsfsf
>
> sadas sfafaf fsaafads fdsafsf dfsfdsf fssfs fsfsfsfs fsfsfs sfsfsfs
>   fsssfsfsf
>
> sadas sfafaf fsaafads fdsafsf dfsfdsf fssfs fsfsfsfs fsfsfs sfsfsfs
>   fsssfsfsf

I used this post: [Adding a scrollbar to a group of widgets in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085696/adding-a-scrollbar-to-a-grid-of-widgets-in-tkinter) as a guide to get to where I am right now. Currently, when I open the window the scroll bar appears on the left side. As soon as I add a line the GUI freezes and I have to close it.

Here is the relevant code:

```
class data_popup():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.top = tk.Toplevel(parent)
        self.top.title("Current Data")
        self.top.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.stop_close)
        #Frames
        self.header_labels_frame = tk.Frame(self.top)
        self.header_labels_frame.pack(side = tk.TOP)
        self.data_frame_1 = tk.Frame(self.top)
        self.data_frame_1.pack(side = tk.BOTTOM)        
        self.header_labels_list = []


        self.data_canvas = tk.Canvas(self.data_frame_1, borderwidth = 0)
        self.data_frame = tk.Frame(self.data_canvas)
        self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.data_frame, orient = 'vertical', command = self.data_canvas.yview)
        self.data_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = self.scrollbar.set)
        self.scrollbar.pack(side = 'right', fill = 'y')
        self.data_canvas.pack(side = "bottom", fill = 'both', expand = True)
        self.data_canvas.create_window((4,4), window = self.data_frame, anchor = 'nw', tags = "self.frame")
        self.data_frame.bind("<Configure>", self.myfunction)
        self.create_header()
        self.data_row_list = list()

    def myfunction(self, event):
        self.data_canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.data_canvas.bbox("all"))
```

Comment: The indentation of your code is incorrect.

Comment: _"As soon as I add a line the GUI freezes and I have to close it. "_ You're not using both `grid` and `pack` in the same window and/or frame, are you? That makes Tkinter enter an infinite loop.

Comment: The indentation is normal on my editor it just copy pasted wrong. I will fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Often, when a GUI freezes in the manner you describe, it is because you use both `grid` and `pack` in the same frame. You aren't showing the code where you add something to the frame, but my guess is, that is what is happening.

Comment: You are correct! I am the labels using a grid. How do I add the canvas to the frame with grid instead of pack? (As in what should the row/column values be)

Comment: The scrollbar and canvas are currently using pack. So I need grid for the scrollbar as well.

Comment: Making them both grid (used row=0,column=0) for both prevents crashes, but it alters the display. Instead of lines every time I try to write it just displays one dot per line. The scroll bar also disappears when I write a line and reappears if I delete them all.

Comment: @DustySack: my recommendation is to forget about the scrollbar initially, and focus on getting the frame to look right. Once you get that, _then_ you can put the frame in a canvas and add scrollbars. Don't try to do too much at one time.

Comment: That is what I did. Adding the scrollbar is what broke how it looks (after I added grid instead of pack, before nothing would display because it froze)

Answer (score 0):

For people who find this post on google I was able to use the information from this post to complete what I needed [Adding a scrollbar to a frame using Tkinter (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245941/adding-a-scrollbar-to-a-frame-using-tkinter-python)